# Recursive jsonSchema maximum call stack

Tags: json, jsonschema, fastify

I'm having issues with a self [referencing jsonSchema](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/structuring.html#recursion).

This one work well :

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
    "allOf": [
        {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/myData"
        },
        {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/foo"
        }
    ],
    "definitions": {
        "foo": {
            "properties": {
                "bar": {
                    "properties": {
                        "bang": {
                            "additionalProperties": {
                                "anyOf": [
                                    {
                                        "$ref": "#/definitions/foo"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "items": {
                                            "$ref": "#/definitions/foo"
                                        },
                                        "type": "array"
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
                            "type": "object"
                        }
                    },
                    "type": "object"
                }
            },
            "type": "object"
        },
        "myData": {
            "properties": {
                "list": {
                    "additionalProperties": {
                        "anyOf": [
                            {
                                "$ref": "#/definitions/myData"
                            },
                            {
                                "items": {
                                    "$ref": "#/definitions/myData"
                                },
                                "type": "array"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    "type": "object"
                }
            },
            "type": "object"
        }
    },
    "type": "object"
}
```

The second one is failling :

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
    "allOf": [
        {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/myData"
        },
        {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/foo"
        }
    ],
    "definitions": {
        "foo": {
            "properties": {
                "bar": {
                    "properties": {
                        "bang": {
                            "items": {
                                "$ref": "#/definitions/foo"
                            },
                            "type": "array"
                        }
                    },
                    "type": "object"
                }
            },
            "type": "object"
        },
        "myData": {
            "properties": {
                "list": {
                    "additionalProperties": {
                        "anyOf": [
                            {
                                "$ref": "#/definitions/myData"
                            },
                            {
                                "items": {
                                    "$ref": "#/definitions/myData"
                                },
                                "type": "array"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    "type": "object"
                }
            },
            "type": "object"
        }
    },
    "type": "object"
}
```

We really need that **bang** property define an array of elements with it's own definition.

This jsonSchema is read by fastify when it throw this error.

> FastifyError [FST_ERR_SCH_SERIALIZATION_BUILD]: Failed building the serialization schema for GET: xxx, due to error Maximum call stack size exceeded

From jsonSchema validator both schemas seems to be valid.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your schema. There must be a bug in some library you're using.

Comment: `Maximum call stack size exceeded` -- does your implementation allow raising the maximum call stack size? It may be set slightly too low for the amount of recursion you are using here, and it is triggering thinking that it is in an endless loop.

Comment: There is an open issue (since 2019): https://github.com/fastify/fast-json-stringify/issues/181
The maintainer has stated they don't have time to fix it, as it would require a major refactor. PR welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a fastify bug : https://github.com/fastify/fast-json-stringify/issues/181.

Library maintainers fixed it on the 19 october 2021, under [fastify v2.7.11](https://github.com/fastify/fast-json-stringify/releases/tag/v2.7.11).